# how does Golang implement OS threads for goroutines?

Tags: go

I'm trying to figure out how golang multiplexes goroutines onto OS threads but I couldn't find the implementation for this in the golang source. I've looked in proc.go and runtime.go. I want to know how threads are initialized and managed and if it uses pthreads.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strategy is different for each os.
Some examples are in [the windows os portion for the Go runtime](https://golang.org/src/runtime/os_windows.go) and 
[the linux os portion for the Go runtime](https://golang.org/src/runtime/os_linux.go)

Comment: do you know what the caller of those modules are. I would like to also see how it handles those functions.

Comment: I would grep around in the runtime package and look closely at proc.go. Is there something in particular you are looking for?

Comment: my main concern was to check if it was using pthreads, but it doesn't look like it now I'm looking to see how it manages the different apis for each system.